# How to select max() value of some of the selected rows?

Tags: plsql

There are two types of rows in document_files table - that have `active=1` or `active=0`. Each document (document_id) can have multiple rows of each type. The goal is to for every document select all rows that have active=1, but only the latest one of all rows that have active=0.

```
select *
from documents d
inner join document_files df on df.document_id = d.id
where ...
-- df.active = 1, select them all
-- or df.active = 0, only select max(df.last_stamp) of all df.active=0 rows for this df.document_id
```

How to achieve this?

I'd use union and group by, but the problem is that a lot of columns are returned, and it wouldn't be optimal to group them all.

Comment: hey please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This section only get the document files with no active record and after that using max () gets the most recent record for the item:

```
select document_id
from (select * from document_files f where f.document_id not in
(select document_id from document_files where active = 1)) dff where dff.last_stamp = 
(
select max(i.last_stamp) from document_files i where i.document_id = dff.document_id
)
```

---

My final sql :

```
  select *
    from documents d
    inner join document_files df on df.document_id = d.id
    where df.active = 1 or 
    df.document_id in
     (
    select document_id
    from (select * from document_files f where f.document_id not in
    (select document_id from document_files where active = 1)) dff where dff.last_stamp = 
    (
    select max(i.last_stamp) from document_files i where i.document_id = dff.document_id
    )
    )
```

Please add some sql fiddle next time so we can test the result

Comment: Did the above answer solve your issue? If so kindly accept it. This helps future users having the same or similar issue, and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered. If it did not solve your issue then what remains?